How to automatically derive a custom order for the side navigation of a website?
I have a relatively simple question about quarto website.
In _quarto.yml I've set auto for contents (sidebar formation):
website:
  sidebar:
    contents: auto

Besides I have the following structure of sub-folders.
/project
--/ 01_basics
    - index.qmd  # title: "Basics"
--/ 02_animals
    - index.qmd  # title: "Animals"

-- _quarto.yml

The rendered sidebar looks as follows (alphabetic order):

Animals
Basics

But I want it to be in the reversed order. Actually I've made the numbering of subfolders to organize the workspace and with the hope that it rules the order of the sidebar. I've added more explicit titles in index files (which seems to be a correct practice), but they eventually had changed the order of sections.
Question: What is the recommended way to order sub-folders in the sidebar without explicit numbering them in titles?

Concerning the sub-folders: Their order ("01_", "02_", ...) is not relevant for the order of the navigation content and there is no recommendation. The index.qmd matter. Within the documentation there is an example where the content is explicitly listed within the _quarto.yml. This lets you define the order. Also, within the section "Auto Generation" it is mentioned that "Order is alphabetical (by filename) unless a numeric order field is provided in document metadata.". Hence you could also provide an order.

So how you would like to proceed here? Is it suitable for you to set up the _quarto.yml as in the documentation? Or do you need the named folders like in the above example? If so, it could be possible to write a pre-render script which populates the index.qmd with their needed order.

@Jan, Thank you! I would prefer not to manually edit _quarto.yml for the navigation. So , your idea with the script would be great, indeed.

Okay, so you would 1) Keep the folder names as they are (numbered, 01_, 02_, ...) and 2) like to have a pre-render script which sets up the order automatically according to the numbers of the folder (such that manually set are only the folder names)? Is this correct? Then I try to write an answer later.

@Jan, they just can be possible. Any number from 01 to 99 can be possible, but from 01 to 20 are common. I may be complicating things, but I think this is a peculiarity of electronic resources - they are presented as prepared, so you have to reserve them for future work (and not constantly rename and move chapters manually).

@Jan, no :) just 01_pattern. My mistake!

@Jan, The only thing to admit is that forlders may appear as 01_, 02_, 04_ and 99_.

The numbering of the subfolders containing the different index.qmd has no relevance for the order of the navigation items within the sidebar. Generally there are some possibilities for defining a custom order:

Set it within the _quarto.yml (see also Side Navigation within the Quarto docs), e.g.
...
    contents:
      - text: "Introduction"
        href: introduction.qmd
      - section: "Basics"
        href: basics-summary.qmd


Use Auto Generation:
sidebar:
    contents: auto

Then for the order we have (from the docs):

Order is alphabetical (by filename) unless a numeric order field is provided in document metadata.

See also the discussions and quarto-dev/quarto-cli#6129 and quarto-dev/quarto-cli#7660 for similar questions.


In your example, you have several subfolders, numbered e.g. 04_folder, and would like to order the navigation content as defined by the number of the folder. Similar to the second point above, we therefore could set a corresponding order within the different index.qmd. It would e.g. look like this:
/project
--/ 01_basics
    - index.qmd  # title: "Basics",    order: 1
--/ 02_animals
    - index.qmd  # title: "Animals",   order: 2
--/ 04_humans
    - index.qmd  # title: "Humans",    order: 4
--/ 99_appendix
    - index.qmd  # title: "Appendix",  order: 99

This can be achieved by using a Pre-Render script. Here is one example using Python (may have to be refined for your use case, but generally works for a minimal example):
prepare.py
import os

rootdir = os.getcwd()
folders = [fo for fo in os.scandir(rootdir) if fo.name[2] == "_"]

for fo in folders:
    for filename in os.listdir(fo):
        if filename == "index.qmd":
            with open(os.path.join(fo, filename), "r") as f:
                lines = [line for line in f.readlines() 
                         if not line.startswith("order: ")]
                
                index = lines.index("---\n", 1)
                lines.insert(index, "order: " + str(int(fo.name[:2])) + "\n")
            with open(os.path.join(fo, filename), "w") as ff:
                ff.writelines(lines)

Locate this script within your project directory and reference it within the _quarto.yml via
project:
  ...
  pre-render: prepare.py

Then it provides the order field within the respective document metadata inside the index.qmd and you obtain your desired order.


thank you a lot. I didn't know about this pre-render feature. That' nice.
